# Why there is no way to change data bound to Django form?

Tags: django, django-forms

I spent several hours trying to understand why cannot I perform saving model action creating only one form instance for saving and validation as well as rendering blank form. (I have a lot of Yii background.)

I faced a problem that I simply cannot set data to model ("bind" in Django terminology). The way from Django documentation when I have to create different models seemed ugly for me first.

Then I found this in Django documentation.

> If you have a bound Form instance and want to change the data somehow, or if you want to bind an unbound Form instance to some data, create another Form instance. There is no way to change data in a Form instance. Once a Form instance has been created, you should consider its data immutable, whether it has data or not.

I understand that this restriction is for some particular reason. So, what's this reason?

**UPD** View code example

```
def register(request: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse:
    organization = forms.Organization()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        organization.data = request.POST
        organization.full_clean()
        if organization.is_valid():
            organization.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('view'))
    return render(request, 'main/organizations/register.html', {
        'form': organization,
    })
```

Rendering is performed with Crispy Forms. Just `{% crispy form %}`.

Form is simple model form.

Comment: Can you show us code examples? In my opinion you can use a single form for validation/saving or for rendering blank form.

Comment: you don't need to call `full_clean` as this is done for you when you check `is_valid`

Comment: @Anentropic I understood already. It's slightly hard to see what is done under the hood. After I had seen just `self.errors` without parentheses, I didn't find out that it calls `self.errors()` method. So, thanks for pointing at mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not very clear what you are trying to ask, but here is a simple example of a view with a model form:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def myview(request):
    form = MyModelForm(data=request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid()
        saved_obj = form.save()
        return redirect('success_url')
    return render(request, 'myform_template.html', {'form': form})
```

When you visit the view initially you will get a blank form (because `request.POST` is empty so the form data is `None` i.e. the form is not 'bound')

You should set your form action in the HTML to post to the same url, simplest way is blank action: `<form action="" method="post">`

When you submit the form `request.POST` will contain the submitted data, so the form will be bound. If the form is valid we save a new model instance, then it is good practice to redirect. If the form is not valid the form will be redisplayed with the data the user submitted, along with error messages.

If you want to edit an existing model instance the pattern looks like:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

def myview(request, pk):
    existing_obj = get_object_or_404(MyModel, pk=pk)
    form = MyModelForm(data=request.POST or None, instance=existing_obj)
    if form.is_valid()
        saved_obj = form.save()
        return redirect('success_url')
    return render(request, 'myform_template.html', {'form': form})
```

In this case when you initially load the page the form will be filled with the existing values from the model instance instead of a blank form.

All of the above can be done in less lines of code using [Django class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/), but they hide what is happening behind a layer of abstraction, so I think probably it's useful to see the basic form handling pattern of Django.

See docs for the `render` and `get_object_or_404` shortcut functions here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/

Comment: `data=request.POST or None` is nice trick. I saw in JS code. Thanks!